# Java Multi Dimensional Array Program Trouble

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, compiler-errors

I don't understand why i'm getting these errors when i compile my code.

Error: F:\G\programA: operator * cannot be applied to int,double[]

Error: F:\G\programA: operator - cannot be applied to double,double[]

```
import java.io.*;

public class programA
{
  public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException
  {
    BufferedReader myInput = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));

  int points = 100, dimension = 3;

  double [] length;
  length = new double [dimension];

  double [][] loc;
  loc = new double [points][dimension];

   for (int x = 0; x < points; x++){
  for (int y = 0; y < dimension; y++){
   location [x][y]= (Math.random() * (2 *length)) - length;
  }
  }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the code isnt clear, I am assuming you need

```
loc [x][y]= (Math.random() * (2 *length[y])) - length[y];
```

Math Operations cannot be done between an array and a number.

Comment: more likely he needs `length[y]`, not `length[dimension]` which will get an out-of-bounds exception

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> 2 *length
> ```

You're multiplying an array by an int. Not going to happen. The code around that is somewhat unclear, but since you're trying to set a single array element you'll want to get a single element of `length`, such as by `length[0]` or `length[someIntInRange]`.

Also, `location [x][y]` should be `loc[x][y]` as there is no field called location.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand why i'm getting these errors when i compile my
>   code.
>
> Error: F:\G\programA: operator * cannot be applied to int,double[]
>
> Error: F:\G\programA: operator - cannot be applied to double,double[]

You are trying to multiply an `int` and later a `double` against an ***array*** of type `double`.  This is not possible.  If you want to multiply against all values in the array, you need to iterate over it to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is an undefined operation here...

```
double [] length;
length = new double [dimension];
...
(2 *length)
```

You need to select a value from the length array.